# lmfit saving function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, save, curve-fitting, lmfit

I've got an issue with

```
save_modelresult(result, 'S:\Doc\Python\Results\modelresult.csv')
```

Well the save is complete, but the organization of this data is very poor. Does anyone know of any tricks/ways how to store my results in organized columns?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lmfit's `model.save_modelresult()` function saves the ModelResult as JSON that is intended to be loaded with `load_modelresult` which will turn that saved representation into a working ModelResult in another Python session.  It's not necessarily meant to be human-readable. Then again, it can be read in with the `json` library if you want.

For organizing that output in a human-readable form, I would suggest looking at the `fit_report()` method of ModelResult and the `lmfit.printfuncs.fit_report()` function that it uses.  The simplest thing to do is probably just save that fit report to a file, say like this:

```
# save fit report to a file:
with open('fit_result.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(result.fit_report())
```

Comment: Thank You for comment. I'd like to ask You about Your last suggestion, which is saving report to a file, can You suggest how to do this?

Comment: I updated the answer to include more explicit instructions on how to save the text report to a file.